# How to differentiate between trees and buildings in OpenCV and NumPy in Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, classification

I am trying to classify buildings and trees in digital elevation models.

Trees normally look like this: [image]

Buildings normally look something like this: [image]

Note the increased disorder in trees compared to buildings. I originally tried to use np.var to differentiate between the two but I am getting inconsistent results. Is there any other non machine learning way to classify these two, preferably on the basis of increased disorder in trees?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site does not serve as general issue solving portal. The community will hapilly lead you to a working solution, but you should share a bit of code showing what you have done already and didnt work. Read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and How do I ask a good question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: My answer might be super overfitted and wrong, as it is based on just the two sample images

Approach 1 :

Just classify based on the 'squareness' -

```
delta_x = |x_min - x_max|, delta_y = |y_min - y_max|
spread_ratio = delta_y/delta_x
if spread_ratio > thresh:
   classify as tree
else:
  classify as building
```

Approach 2:
 Your images have very different colors. If that corresponds to height, you can just find a thresholding based on average height of a tree and building

Comment: Hey, can you let me know if this works? I'm curious